# Angular passing variable to function call

Tags: angular, function, addeventlistener

I'm adding EvenetListener to some hyperlink.
And on click it consoles some data.

```
elements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.path[1].id)));
```

Now I want to call some function and pass that data to that function instead of console.log
I'm trying this, but it does not works. Function is not working at all. How can I do this?

```
elements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click',  (e)=>this.someFunc.bind(e.path[1].id)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use `bind()` method or arrow function, not mix them. Try the following

```js
elements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click',  (e) => this.someFunc(e.path[1].id)));
```

OR

```js
elements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click',  this.someFunc.bind(this));

private someFunc(event) {
  const id = event.path[1].id;
  this.id = id;    // <-- `this` keyword refers to the scope of the class due to `bind(this)`
}
```

[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method is used to denote the meaning of `this` keyword inside the callback function. If you aren't using any member variables/methods inside the callback using the `this` keyword, `bind` could be omitted in your case.

```js
elements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click',  this.someFunc));

private someFunc(event) {
  const id = event.path[1].id;
  this.id = id;    // <-- `this` keyword refers to the scope of the function - will throw an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click', this.someFunc(e.path[1].id)));
```

Comment: So... where does `e` come from in `e.path[1].id`?